# How to say that you are available on weekday except one day (e.g., Tuesday)

Tags: grammar

My boss is arranging a meeting with no specific date and I want to say to him that I'm available any day from Monday-Friday except Tuesday. But I want to sound gramatically correct.

So I was thinking of saying "I'm available on weekday but sadly not on Tuesdays."
But this doesn't sound correct to me, what do you think?

Comment: Any weekday but Tuesday.

Comment: Basically you are already there **any day from Monday through Friday except Tuesday.** That is grammatical, clear, and succinct.

Comment: @Jeff: Mine is grammatical, clear, and more succinct. Four words and all the facts are in. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto I can see that it may seem that I was commenting on your comment. I was not. I was pointing out that the OP already had a formulation that was grammatical, etc except for the odd locution **from Monday-Friday**. Thank you for the opportunity to clarify what I was addressing.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are bounding it by the work week, you could say

> Any **weekday** but Tuesday.

If you wanted to include Sunday and Saturday, you could say

> Any **day** but Tuesday.

but since it is your boss, it would probably be understood to mean the work week.

You could also say

> All week except for Tuesday.

or

> I’m not available on Tuesday, but any other day is fine.